# ROS2 Ignition Gazebo in VM with ogre1

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I try to test gazebo ignition through a Ubuntu 18.04 VM with OpenGL capabilities and I obtain this error when I launch :

> ign gazebo lights.sdf -v 4

and it's all blurry and the interface is unworkable at all.

Is there some limitations using ogre1 in Gazebo for now ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24615/ros2-ignition-gazebo-in-vm-with-ogre1/) by [Tomlogan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24765/tomlogan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been using Ignition with Ogre 1 and 2 without any issues both on Ubuntu and inside Docker containers. So I guess the problem is coming from the VM. Does Gazebo-classic work for you?

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomlogan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24765/tomlogan/) on 2020-03-20**:
Yes it works, I succeed with docker and rocker but in my VM it was a very strange behavior, maybe it comes from the OpenGL version inside it (2.0)